# Error processing file named sonar-reports/oclint.xml

Tags: xcode, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am facing an issue when I am trying analyzing iPhone app code with the help of sonarqube.

I am getting below error when trying to execute sonar-runner from app root directory.

```
11:06:17.040 INFO  - Index files<br/>
11:06:18.276 INFO  - 214 files indexed<br/>
11:06:18.966 INFO  - Quality profile for objc: OCLint<br/>
11:06:19.016 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...<br/>
11:06:19.020 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 4 ms<br/>
11:06:19.020 INFO  - Sensor ObjectiveCSquidSensor...<br/>
11:06:19.334 INFO  - Sensor ObjectiveCSquidSensor done: 314 ms<br/>
11:06:19.334 INFO  - Sensor Objective-C SurefireSensor...<br/>
11:06:19.334 INFO  - parsing sonar-reports<br/>
11:06:19.334 INFO  - Sensor Objective-C SurefireSensor done: 0 ms<br/>
11:06:19.335 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.coverage.CoberturaSensor@6544899b...<br/>
11:06:19.342 INFO  - Sensor 
org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.coverage.CoberturaSensor@6544899b done: 7 ms<br/>
11:06:19.342 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.violations.OCLintSensor@6da54910...<br/>
11:06:19.342 INFO  - Processing OCLint report /Users/org/Documents/C/ISH/projects/Proj1/mobile2.2.0.5/mobile/ios/Proj1-Mobile/./sonar-reports/oclint.xml<br/>
11:06:19.346 ERROR - Error processing file named /Users/org/Documents/C/ISH/projects/Proj1/mobile2.2.0.5/mobile/ios/Proj1-Mobile/./sonar-reports/oclint.xml<br/>
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/org/Documents/C/ISH/projects/Proj1/mobile2.2.0.5/mobile/ios/Proj1-Mobile/./sonar-reports/oclint.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.violations.OCLintParser.parseReport(OCLintParser.java:49) ~[sonar-objective-c-plugin-0.4.0.jar:na]
```

Thanks in advance ,Let me know if someone faced same problem before.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you're using the community SonarQube Objective-C plugin (https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c), the best best to get some help is to create an issue here : https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c/issues

Comment: Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue before, I solved it by using
    `sudo ./run-sonar.sh`
The reason could be the oclint.xml is generated by root user before, and you are running as non-root user, so no privilege for you to access oclint.xml

Another possible reason is the dot(.) prefix in sonar-project.properties, `Proj1-Mobile/./sonar-reports/oclint.xml`, try to remove the ./ prefix in your properties file for the oclint.xml